# Pushing Git non-branch references to a remote

Tags: git, git-branch, git-remote

Git non-branch references (not branches, tags, remotes and notes) work just fine in a local machine but I have trubles to push them in a remote:

```sh
$ git update-ref refs/exp/ee01 6a534fb5f9aad615ebeeb9d01ebe558a679a3cd1
```

It was successfully created:

```
$ cat .git/refs/exp/ee01
6a534fb5f9aad615ebeeb9d01ebe558a679a3cd1
$ git for-each-ref refs/exp
6a534fb5f9aad615ebeeb9d01ebe558a679a3cd1 commit refs/exp/ee01
```

Pushing it:

```
$ git push origin exp/ee01
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/dmpetrov/example-get-started-exp.git
 * [new branch]      refs/exp/ee01 -> refs/exp/ee01
```

However, I don't see it when I clone this repo:

```
$ git clone https://github.com/dmpetrov/example-get-started-exp.git
$ cd example-get-started-exp/
$ git for-each-ref refs/exp  # it returns nothing
```

How to push non-branch references properly?

EDIT: I can fetch it by name to FETCH_HEAD. Ideally, I should see\fetch all the new refs without knowing the names in advance.

```
$ git fetch origin exp/ee01
From https://github.com/dmpetrov/example-get-started-exp
 * branch            refs/exp/ee01 -> FETCH_HEAD
```

Comment: If you're pushing the ref to origin, when you clone it in a fresh repo, then it's going to appear under `refs/remotes/origin`.  There's a lot of documentation on [git-push](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push).  Perhaps there's some way to preserve the original ref structure when pushing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Refspecs as a general concept are great, but there's a somewhat unfinished feeling to them.

When you first clone some existing repository, your `git clone` uses a built-in equivalent to `git remote add` to add the remote name.  As [the `git remote` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-remote) notes (a bit [elliptically - see meaning 2a](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/elliptical)):

> With `-t <branch>` option, instead of the default glob refspec for the remote to track all branches under the `refs/remotes/<name>/` namespace, a refspec to track only `<branch>` is created. You can give more than one `-t <branch>` to track multiple branches without grabbing all branches.

What this boils down to is the fact that after `git clone`, the (single) default fetch refspec for the new clone is:

```
+refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<name>/*
```

where `<name>` is the name from the `-o` option, or `origin` if you did not specify such an option.<sup>1</sup>

What it doesn't mention explicitly, and is not obvious, is that the `remote.remote.fetch` setting in a Git configuration file is cumulative.<sup>2</sup>  This means that you can open up the existing `.git/config` file, once `git clone` has created it, and edit it.  You will see:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

You can change this to add another line, so that it reads:

```
[remote "origin"]
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
    fetch = +refs/exp/*:refs/exp/*
```

Now any `git fetch origin` will overwrite any of your existing `refs/exp/` references with those that are on `origin`.  Fetching with `prune = true` or with the `-p` or `--prune` option will delete any of your existing `refs/exp/*` references that have no corresponding name on `origin`.

If you wish to replace their `refs/exp/*` names with your own `refs/rexp/origin/*` names, make the second line read:

```
    fetch = +refs/exp/*:refs/rexp/origin/*
```

and now you have invented exp-tracking names.

(Given that there is no `refs/tags/*:refs/tags/*` refspec—with or without a leading `+` sign—you might wonder how tags work at all.  The answer here is "somewhat magically, with internal rules that cannot be expressed through a refspec".  That's part of what I mean about the somewhat unfinished feeling.  It's also not obvious what to put in during a `git clone`, but note that `git clone -c name=value` lets you write configuration values at `git clone` time.  You still need to somehow know that the remote you're cloning has `refs/exp/*` names, though.)

---

<sup>1</sup>In a forthcoming Git release, the `-o` option is likely to have a configurable default, so that leaving out `-o` won't necessarily mean *use `origin`*, but for now, that's what it always means.

<sup>2</sup>In contrast, a setting such as `user.name` or `user.email` uses only the *last* value.  That is, if your configuration file says:

```
[user]
    name = fred
    name = flintstone
```

then `user.name` is `flintstone`: the earlier `fred` value has been discarded in favor of the later `flintstone` one.  A cumulative setting can only obtained with `git config --get-all` or `git config --get-regexp`; it comes out as one line per value.  See [the `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) for more details.

Comment: thank you for the comprehensive answer! That works! I'm wondering if there a way to make this experience smoother for the repo consumers (who might not know about this tricks): 1) what commands the repo consumers should run to get the same result; 2) what I should do to make a regular `git clone` pull all the result.

Comment: I accepted this - it gives a solid answer to the question. Regarding my followup questions - I'll try to figure that out or create a separate question.

Comment: @DmitryPetrov: "how to make it all smoother" is a good (but separate) question, and is the rest of what I mean about the idea of refspecs being somewhat unfinished: mechanism without policy.)

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, if you want to push some random thing into a remote into a new (in the remote) branch, then you have to first push an existing branch from your local and then you can push the id you want:

```
git push origin master:new-branch
git push origin the-id-i-really-want:new-branch
```

Comment: You don't need to do this. You can just do `git push origin the-id-i-really-want:refs/heads/new-branch` from the start.